# Add a prefix to filenames retrieved with wget using the --content-disposition option

Tags: ubuntu, wget

I have to download some files through a URL pattern: `https://www.server.org/data/2021/{i}` where i can vary from 1 to 1000.

Files are pdfs and they all have they own name, e.g.:

```
https://www.server.org/data/2021/1 ====> document_about_feature.pdf   
https://www.server.org/data/2021/2 ====> "activity report.pdf"    
https://www.server.org/data/2021/3 ====> "2021-financial analysis from bla bla.pdf" 
...
```

For the moment I'm getting those files using [`wget`](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/) as follow:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

for i in {1..1000}
do
  URL="https://www.server.org/data/2021/${i}"
  wget -nv --content-disposition "${URL}"
done
```

It's the only way I found to keep the original file names when downloading them (without the `--content-disposition` flag, the files are named 1.pdf, 2.pdf, 3.pdf, etc). So it works fine, but I would like to keep the link between `i` and the file name by appending a prefix (or suffix) to the file name:

```
https://www.server.org/data/2021/1 ====> 1_document_about_feature.pdf   
https://www.server.org/data/2021/2 ====> "2_activity report.pdf"    
https://www.server.org/data/2021/3 ====> "3_2021-financial analysis from bla bla.pdf"   
...
```

How could I properly achieve this (Ubuntu 22.04.3)?

Version: GNU Wget (1.21.2 built on linux-gnu).

Answer (score 1):

I'd probably just download and afterwards rename; something like

```bash
#!/bin/bash
# use this directory as tempfile prefix
# (so that move becomes a single-filesystem operation)
tmpdirname="$(mktemp -d -p --tmpdir . "fetch_XXXXXXX")"
for i in {1..1000}; do
  URL="https://www.server.org/data/2021/${i}"

  # I'm almost certain you'll want file names 0001,…,0999,1000; not 1…1000
  formatted="$(printf '%04d' i)"

  dirname="${tmpdirname}/${formatted}"
  mkdir "${dirname}"
  pushd "${dirname}"
    wget -nv --content-disposition "${URL}"
    filename=*
  popd
  mv -- "${dirname}/${filename}" "${formatted} ${filename}"
  rmdir "${dirname}"
done
rmdir "${tmpdirname}
```

Personally, I remember `wget` being buggy around `--content-disposition`, at least according to its `man` page.

I tend towards `curl` these days¹, so I'd replace `wget -nv --content-disposition "${URL}"` with `curl --remote-name --remote-header-name`:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
# use this directory as tempfile prefix
# (so that move becomes a single-filesystem operation)
tmpdirname="$(mktemp -d -p --tmpdir . "fetch_XXXXXXX")"
for i in {1..1000}; do
  URL="https://www.server.org/data/2021/${i}"

  # I'm almost certain you'll want file names 0001,…,999,1000; not 1…1000
  formatted="$(printf '%04d' i)"

  dirname="${tmpdirname}/${formatted}"
  mkdir "${dirname}"
  pushd "${dirname}"
    curl --remote-name --remote-header-name -- "${URL}"
    filename=*
  popd
  mv -- "${dirname}/${filename}" "${formatted} ${filename}"
  rmdir "${dirname}"
done
rmdir "${tmpdirname}
```

---

¹ good testing, very modern protocol support, unlike `wget` properly reuses TLS sessions, leading to faster connections at lower server load; and no logical bug where `--` can be a valid argument…

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'm facing an error at line 4: `tmpdirname=...` : `mktemp: too many templates
Try 'mktemp --help' for more information.`

Comment: After the [doc](https://www.gnu.org/software/autogen/mktemp.html), should't the current dir (i.e. the `.`) be placed just after the  `-p` flag instead? : `mktemp -p . -d --tmpdir 'fetch_XXXXXXX'`

Comment: Also, after `popd`, the `filename` variable which was the actual filename before executing `popd` is set to the star `*` character. I don't know why it changed.